# Laravel-5, Associating a role with a user

Tags: php, eloquent, roles, laravel-5, middleware

Ok, so here I still messing with pivots like a true newbie on Laravel 5.

Everything is working fine however I need to associate a role with a user, there could be many roles so I need to cycle through and find the right one and if I do return a value of true.

Everything works as it should to this point, I have this for my User to Role relationship.

```
    public function roles()
    {       
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }
```

I have created a new middleware like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

       if ( ! $request->user()->hasRole())
       {
          return redirect('/');
       }

       return $next($request);

    }
```

So I then need to create the hasRole in User in order to confirm my user has the required role.  In this case there could be 7 roles, one of them is Administrator so I need to cycle through and find out if he does have the role, which is where I am stuck.

I need to put something in the User model along the lines of

```
public function hasRole()
{
   foreach roles as role 
   find "Administrator" 
   if you do return true

   Otherwise return false
}
```

Poor on my part I know however you get the idea, I am struggling to get to grips with eloquent but I am getting there.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using what you have, you could do something like:

**Improved**
After digging through the collection class in laravel, found a better solution.

```
public function hasRole()
{
    return $this-roles->contains('name', 'admin')
}
```

**Original Answer**

```
public function hasRole() 
{
  return count($this->roles->filter(function($role) {
    return $role->name == 'admin';
  })) == 1;

}
```